# How to generate PDF with images in windows store app using c# & XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, pdf-generation, windows-8.1

I have a requirement to generate PDF file in my app.  I want to display the student records in PDF with their images.  I have google a lot but i am not able find any example with c# & xaml.  I have tried these links -

[Link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532207.aspx)

[Link2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx)

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Apitron offers their [Apitron PDF Kit library](http://apitron.com/Product/pdf-kit) which works for windows store apps, Xamarin and other platforms. It's paid of course. This [blogspost](http://blog.apitron.com/2015/03/create-and-load-PDF-forms-in-universal-applications-using-windows-store-and-windows-phone-PDF-library.html) shows how to create a simple PDF form in windows store app. Pretty similar to student record.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [component one](http://www.componentone.com/), they have done a lot of usefull components, am testing the PDF render/generator for Windows Store Apps it works very good so far, take a look at the new demo-Trial on their web page...